# Using Windows XP Mode Virtual Machine on a Domain

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, authentication, active-directory, virtual-machines

I've followed the instructions and installed and configured the Windows Virtual PC XP Mode. I've added it as a machine on the network and can log into it and use network resources.

In the process I removed the saved credentials, which are just a default local login to the VM.

I need to know how to set this so that the VM auto logs in with the domain account credentials used to log into the physical computer.

Google hasn't helped me find the answer.

Comment: Doesn't standard the standard XP autologon procedure work ?http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

Comment: @Helvick, I think he wants XP to be logged in as the user who logged into Win7; not the same user every time.

Comment: Ah - makes sense.

Comment: any chance of some feedback on this question. It's been lingering for months now...

Comment: How did you configure you xpmode ? 1 xpmode per computer for all you user ? or 1 vm per user per machine? You can already have access to Windows 7 shared drive with \\tsclient\(driveLetter), same with printers.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Integration Features on the Tools menu.

Comment: It's already on. It's set to Auto Enable, Enable at startup.

Comment: Under Logon Credentials it says None. However, the screen that comes up only has one button which is delete saved credentials, and that is disabled.

Comment: The user still has to login the first time; after that it shouldn't ask again, and should cache the credentials. Is this not the case?

Comment: Actually its not autologon, the Xpmode only go into hibernation and stay forever logged on.

Comment: Right, autologon has nothing to do with the integrated logon provided by the integration software installed on XP Mode images (also available for download from MS separately).